# Network timeouts on real device, but not on emulator

Tags: java, android, mysql, jdbc

I have an application querying a remote database to log in, using jdbc.  I have an android 5.0 emulator which can connect to the db quickly and with no complaints.  However, on every hardware device I have tested on, connecting to the database fails with the error

`com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to dallas113.arvixeshared.com/207.210.200.136 (port 3306): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)`

Like I said, the database works and is up, and all the devices have a fast internet connection.  I do have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` set in my manifest.  I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you added mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar ???

Comment: @Anptk yes of course